# What is the actual (not official) size of the Ryanair "baggage sizer"?

Tags: air-travel, hand-luggage, ryanair

I know that this question could sound a little bit dumb since Ryanair always sends lot of emails specifying the dimensions of the allowed hand luggage but I am not interested in the "formal" answer but in the "informal" one.

In every airport where Ryanair flies there is a blue box (baggage sizer) where you and the airport staff can put your hand luggage to test if it can be accepted on board. What I would like to know is the dimension of that box (which is of course bigger than the allowed size).

I've been a pretty frequent Ryanair flyer (one flight per month) and I always used the same luggage which was ok for the old box even if bigger than the allowed size.

Few weeks ago Ryanair introduced the possibility to bring a second hand luggage on board. In doing so they also changed the dimensions of the blue box which now has two compartments (one for the main hand luggage, still bigger than the allowed size, and one for the small one). 
My old luggage doesn't fit anymore in the new boxes so I guess I'll have to buy a new one, hence the need to know how far can I go with the size of the luggage.

Comment: Just to understand you better...

Your carry on luggage fitted before and now it does not? How is this possible if the new blue box is bigger than the allowed size?

In any case...

Is this a backpack or something else?

Comment: The blue box has always been bigger than the allowed size (I guess 90% of the carry on luggages I've seen wouldn't pass a strict control). Now it is just "less bigger" than before.

Comment: Frying in 2 days, if I see the box anywhere, I can try to measure it.

Comment: @tohecz please do, that would be fantastic - I'd bounty your answer for that :)

Comment: why not use it the way it's meant to be used? check out the maximum allowed size of the bag, then buy one that is just a little smaller than maximum allowed. Then, in case you overstuff it, it will still fit the sizer, as they've allowed a little extra space for people like you. Why push it to the limit?

Comment: @PeterPerháč I get your point but the size allowed by Ryanair is really small. Expecially during winter/autumn, when you really need to bring with you clothes that occupy more space having such a small luggage means you will surely have to board an extra luggage.

Comment: @tohecz any luck?

Comment: @MarkMayo Ah sorry for not responding, pal. Unfortunately not, they don't have it at PRG and they fly from T3 at CDG while I was at T2D :-/

Comment: @tohecz curses, the hunt continues ;)

Comment: @PeterPerháč Because that's what Ryanair is all about! If like me you just prefer to follow reasonable rules, you don't fly with them ;-)

Comment: When did they change the bag sizer from being top-loader (as shown above) to a front loader - a very clever move, since the wheels now snag the new frame/gauge and so a bag that previously fitted will now get you a €50 gate charge!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I measured the box in BSL and it was 21,2 x 41,2 x 58 cm (8.3" x 16.22" x 22.8"). However, the 58 cm are not exact because firstly the box has two rounded rods at the bottom, which makes it slightly smaller at these points, but it's open to the top so this dimension won't matter to much I guess.

[image: Ryanair baggage sizer]

Comment: I change the accepted answer from mine to yours since you provided the exact measures while I didn't have a meter with me.

Comment: I took a meter with me only due to this question ;-)

Comment: And I put a bounty on this answer because we value when someone actually goes and does something to answer a question.

Comment: Thanks! Probably the most useful thing I have ever done while waiting for the boarding call...

Comment: +1 (and more, if it were possible) for doing this to provide the answer.

Comment: I just joint the travel.stackexchange.com to vote your answer! :D

Comment: Does anyone know the actual size of the "handbag" sizer box at the front ? Is it also bigger than the official stated size ? I may have to take a tape measure with me next time ;-)

Answer (score 7):

I had the opportunity to check the measures of the Ryanair "baggage sizer" yesterday even though I hadn't a meter with me. My hand luggage fitted almost perfectly so I can say that the size of the baggage sizer is roughly 23 x 43 x 50 (the last measure is probably the least important one since it is open on top).

In the end, you have something like 3 or 4 centimeters more than the allowed size for each measure.

Comment: wow, considering their official dimensions are 20x40x55, that's definitely different enough to matter to some people.

Comment: Height definitly matters. I had to pay excess once for that. They first used the box, where it fited and than they actualy used a meter. It was really bad because it exceeded for 1cm in height and it was an handle. Back then they were beeing very strict.

Answer (score 7):

Update (November 2018):

**All** passengers get one free **small** carry-on bag (sometimes described as a "personal bag", laptop bag, or handbag) to be placed under the seat in front. Officially, this small carry-on bag must be 40x25x20cm. According [to this article on the Ryanair website (s.v. Q5)](https://corporate.ryanair.com/news/new-bag-policy-from-november-will-cut-check-bag-fees-reduce-boarding-delays/), the sizer is **42**x**30**x20cm.

**If you have priority boarding**, you can, in addition to the aforementioned small carry-on bag, take a wheeled bag of 55x40x20cm (I cannot find any up-to-date information on the sizer for this).

Comment: Flew out of London Stansted a week ago with Ryanair, with a small carry-on bag that was, I suspect (too scared to actually try it in the sizer, since I did not want to draw attention to myself), slightly over the sizer dimensions (42x30x20cm), but I was **not** stopped. It fitted easily under the seat in front (middle seats are best, owing to the positioning of the cross-bars). Then again, it was not a very crowded flight, and it departed late, so perhaps the staff could not be bothered to challenge anybody (I did not see anybody asked to put their carry-on bag in the sizer).