# Is the Ikea Upptäcka bag accepted as cabin baggage on Ryanair flights?

Tags: hand-luggage, ryanair

I was wondering whether the [IKEA UPPTÄCKA “cabin bag on wheels”](http://www.ikea.com/gb/en/catalog/products/50209083/) is accepted as cabin baggage on Ryanair flights? [Ryanair’s regulations](http://www.ryanair.com/en/terms-and-conditions/regulations-cabinbaggage/) allow bags with maximum dimensions of 55cm x 40cm x 20cm. IKEA’s website states the dimensions of the bag as 50cm x 40cm x 20.5cm. That puts the depth at half a centimeter too much. I can’t quite imagine that being a problem. But as I’ve never flown with Ryanair, and given the company’s reputation of looking for ways to squeeze some extra surcharges out of their passengers, I’d just like to make sure. Who knows, they might have staff training courses on “how to recognize the oversized bags of the most popular brands.” IKEA’s stated dimensions might also not be accurate, or depending on how they measured, the difference might be bigger.

It’s not the main question, but I’d also appreciate knowing whether the [“collapsible cabin bag on wheels”](http://www.ikea.com/gb/en/catalog/products/90241142/) is accepted. The stated dimensions of 48cm x 35cm x 20cm would seem to fall within the regulations, but it doesn’t hurt to make sure. It’s smaller than the other bag, and when I saw it in the store, seemed so flimsy I’m not sure it would survive even a single trip. But perhaps it’s more interesting than I thought at first, as Ryanair’s weight limit is 10kg, and this bag only weighs 1.85kg (compared to 2.75kg for the other bag).

Comment: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/23624/what-is-the-actual-not-official-size-of-the-ryanair-baggage-sizer?rq=1 This question is probably useful. Note that in my (out of date) experience of Ryanair, there is no opportunity given to squeeze and make fit. If it doesn't go in immediatley, then it's check + pay.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the related question. Based on that, I think the bag would fit in Ryanair’s baggage sizer. But it would be great to get confirmation from someone who has tried.

Comment: If you flew with the bag since asking the question, please can you add a verified answer with your experience. Thank you.

Comment: @DanielGerson: I wound up booking a different airline. I did do a quick check at the airport with the Ryanair cabin baggage sizer. It was a tight fit: the bag slid, rather than fell, down the sizer under its own weight. But I did *not* have to push to get it in. I’ve been told they will accept it in that case, but I am not sure. Next time I have an opportunity to check, I will ask the Ryanair staff.

Comment: @Rinzwind Thanks! I ended up going with easyjet. It fit into baggage sizer no problems, although in both directions they checked the luggage in at the gate due to limited capacity. :-)

Answer (score 4):

If the dimensions on Ikea's site are accurate, both bags should be accepted.  The first bag is listed as 5mm too thick, but that's not a problem because that dimension of a suitcase is the most amenable to squishing (just don't overpack it).

The reason I say "should be accepted" rather than "will be accepted" is not because I haven't flown with those particular bags on that particular airline, but rather because I have flown a lot with other bags on other airlines.  One particular incident which compels me here is when I took a standard Travelpro rollaboard on a Delta flight and was told that it was too large at the gate.  I told them it was within spec but they were having none of it.  I even put it in one of those measuring devices they have at airports.  They still took it away from me to check it in.  Then, bizarrely, ten minutes later when I was seated in the plane, they delivered the bag to me, said it was allowed to be carried on, and put it overhead.  So you never know what will happen for sure.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on not overpacking. As you mention, IKEA’s dimensions might not be accurate, I forgot to put that in my question, I will add it. I’m hoping for an answer from someone who has taken these bags on a Ryanair flight.

Comment: I'm not answering as last time I answered a Ryanair question I was out of date but: When I've seen Ryanair checking cabin bags, it is with one of the fixed sized frames you have to insert your bag in to. If the bag was a suitcase type, as opposed to a soft backback or holdall, then if it didn't fit *immediatley* on first try, then it was sent back to be checked. I'd say you might get away with slightly too tall, as it would stick out the top, but not to deep, as it won't go in easily. I don't know how close in size the frame is to the listed maximum size though.