# EasyJet underseat bag size

Tags: luggage, hand-luggage, easyjet

In the new policy for easyJet, passengers are only allowed to carry a small underseat cabin bag with the measures 45x36x20.

Has anybody actually measured an easyJet bag cage and can share the real measures?

I just found that somebody measured Ryanair's and has 1.2cm extra size in all dimensions. Hopefully somebody has the real measures for easyJet one.

[What is the actual (not official) size of the Ryanair "baggage sizer"?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/23624/what-is-the-actual-not-official-size-of-the-ryanair-baggage-sizer)

Comment: I'm not sure you can guarantee that the sizer is the same everywhere. It would be stupid if you "counted" on a few extra cm and they didn't exist when you need it.

Comment: If the baggage sizer were exactly the same size as the allowed bag size, the latter wouldn’t fit inside the former. The official size is the only one that matters.

Comment: If the baggage doesn't fit into a test cage that is slightly larger than the published allowance, there can be no argument if it won't go in.

Comment: I just want to know the measures of the cage. I haven't asked for advice about how to deal with the airline if there is any issue.

Comment: Why this question is downvoted and the equivalent for Ryanair's is 30 votes up?